# Clear File Upload on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following **[jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8t629359/)** that allows a user to upload an image & it'll display.

However, when the user wants to click the 'x' to remove the image, it doesn't work?

Can someone explain how I achieve this?

```js
$("input[type='file']").on("change", function(event1) {
  src1 = URL.createObjectURL(event1.target.files[0]);
  this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector("label").style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + src1 + ')';
  this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector("label span").style.display = 'none';
  this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector("button").style.display = 'block';
});
```

```css
.form-file-upload-container {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  margin-top: 12px;
}
@media (min-width: 640px) {
  .form-file-upload-container {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px
  }
}
.form-file-upload {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 48.5%;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 3%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}
@media (min-width: 450px) {
  .form-file-upload {
    width: 31.3333%
  }
}
@media (min-width: 750px) {
  .form-file-upload {
    width: 22.75%
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1600px) {
  .form-file-upload {
    width: 14.1666667%;
    margin-right: 2%
  }
}
.form-file-upload:nth-child(2n) {
  margin-right: 0
}
@media (min-width: 450px) {
  .form-file-upload:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-right: 3%
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1600px) {
  .form-file-upload:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-right: 2%
  }
}
@media (min-width: 450px) {
  .form-file-upload:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-right: 0
  }
}
@media (min-width: 750px) {
  .form-file-upload:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-right: 3%
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1600px) {
  .form-file-upload:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-right: 2%
  }
}
@media (min-width: 750px) {
  .form-file-upload:nth-child(4n) {
    margin-right: 0
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1600px) {
  .form-file-upload:nth-child(4n) {
    margin-right: 2%
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1600px) {
  .form-file-upload:nth-child(6n) {
    margin-right: 0
  }
}
.form-file-upload-inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 133.33333%
}
.form-file-upload label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #AFAFB4;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #AFAFB4;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.2s ease, border 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: background 0.2s ease, border 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: background 0.2s ease, border 0.2s ease;
  transition: background 0.2s ease, border 0.2s ease
}
.form-file-upload span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}
.form-file-upload span:before {
  content: '';
  background: url(../img/image-upload-icon.png) no-repeat center center #fff;
  background: url(../img/image-upload-icon.svg) no-repeat center center #fff;
  background-size: 65px 56px;
  display: block;
  width: 65px;
  height: 56px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 5px
}
.form-file-upload input {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1
}
.form-file-upload .close {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -13px;
  right: -13px;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 26px;
  background: white;
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.2s ease, color 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: background 0.2s ease, color 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: background 0.2s ease, color 0.2s ease;
  transition: background 0.2s ease, color 0.2s ease
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-file-upload">
  <div class="form-file-upload-inner">
    <label for="FileOne"><span>Select Image</span>
    </label><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap FileOne"><input type="file" name="FileOne" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file" id="FileOne" aria-invalid="false" /></span>
    <button class="close" type="button">x</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-file-upload">
  <div class="form-file-upload-inner">
    <label for="FileTwo"><span>Select Image</span>
    </label><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap FileOne"><input type="file" name="FileTwo" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file" id="FileTwo" aria-invalid="false" /></span>
    <button class="close" type="button">x</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-file-upload">
  <div class="form-file-upload-inner">
    <label for="FileThree"><span>Select Image</span>
    </label><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap FileOne"><input type="file" name="FileThree" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file" id="FileThree" aria-invalid="false" /></span>
    <button class="close" type="button">x</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add click event to your button.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8t629359/1/) and here is a live working code :

```js
$("input[type='file']").on("change", function(event1) {
  src1 = URL.createObjectURL(event1.target.files[0]);
  this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector("label").style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + src1 + ')';
  this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector("label span").style.display = 'none';
  this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector("button").style.display = 'block';
});
$("button").click(function (){
  this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector("label").style.backgroundImage = 'none';
  this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector("label span").style.display = 'block';
  this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector("button").style.display = 'none';
});
```

```css
.form-file-upload-container {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  margin-top: 12px;
}
@media (min-width: 640px) {
  .form-file-upload-container {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px
  }
}
.form-file-upload {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 48.5%;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 3%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}
@media (min-width: 450px) {
  .form-file-upload {
    width: 31.3333%
  }
}
@media (min-width: 750px) {
  .form-file-upload {
    width: 22.75%
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1600px) {
  .form-file-upload {
    width: 14.1666667%;
    margin-right: 2%
  }
}
.form-file-upload:nth-child(2n) {
  margin-right: 0
}
@media (min-width: 450px) {
  .form-file-upload:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-right: 3%
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1600px) {
  .form-file-upload:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-right: 2%
  }
}
@media (min-width: 450px) {
  .form-file-upload:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-right: 0
  }
}
@media (min-width: 750px) {
  .form-file-upload:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-right: 3%
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1600px) {
  .form-file-upload:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-right: 2%
  }
}
@media (min-width: 750px) {
  .form-file-upload:nth-child(4n) {
    margin-right: 0
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1600px) {
  .form-file-upload:nth-child(4n) {
    margin-right: 2%
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1600px) {
  .form-file-upload:nth-child(6n) {
    margin-right: 0
  }
}
.form-file-upload-inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 133.33333%
}
.form-file-upload label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #AFAFB4;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #AFAFB4;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.2s ease, border 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: background 0.2s ease, border 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: background 0.2s ease, border 0.2s ease;
  transition: background 0.2s ease, border 0.2s ease
}
.form-file-upload span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}
.form-file-upload span:before {
  content: '';
  background: url(../img/image-upload-icon.png) no-repeat center center #fff;
  background: url(../img/image-upload-icon.svg) no-repeat center center #fff;
  background-size: 65px 56px;
  display: block;
  width: 65px;
  height: 56px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 5px
}
.form-file-upload input {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1
}
.form-file-upload .close {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -13px;
  right: -13px;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 26px;
  background: white;
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.2s ease, color 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: background 0.2s ease, color 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: background 0.2s ease, color 0.2s ease;
  transition: background 0.2s ease, color 0.2s ease
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-file-upload">
  <div class="form-file-upload-inner">
    <label for="FileOne"><span>Select Image</span>
    </label><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap FileOne"><input type="file" name="FileOne" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file" id="FileOne" aria-invalid="false" /></span>
    <button class="close" type="button">x</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-file-upload">
  <div class="form-file-upload-inner">
    <label for="FileTwo"><span>Select Image</span>
    </label><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap FileOne"><input type="file" name="FileTwo" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file" id="FileTwo" aria-invalid="false" /></span>
    <button class="close" type="button">x</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-file-upload">
  <div class="form-file-upload-inner">
    <label for="FileThree"><span>Select Image</span>
    </label><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap FileOne"><input type="file" name="FileThree" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file" id="FileThree" aria-invalid="false" /></span>
    <button class="close" type="button">x</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have found a bug :-O If you select a file then delete it then try to upload another (on the same area), it remains blank. Can you help?

Comment: It is working in the snippet I uploaded in my answer. is it not working in your code

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately it isn't working on the snippet either. Can you test upload a photo, cancel it, then test upload a photo in the same part. It doesn't display for me :-(

Comment: Aaaaah. It seems to break when you try to upload the same image a 2nd time :-D That's cool - nobody will ever do that :-) Thank you!!! :)

Comment: well that's true. but I uploaded the same image two times and it is working. maybe a glitch in your connection. well no worries, if it's working on mine then it would work for your users too.